# Issues with JS from Mozilla v21 to IEv8

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction, however, with the below javascript.  It renders fine and does not encounter any errors within firefox, but when going into ie8 no errors are received, nothing runs.

Don't spend too much time on it guys, however any pointers would be much appreciated.  Please see code below;

```
//resetting error messages
function resetMessages() {
//reset errors
var errors = document.getElementsByClassName('error');
while (errors.length != 0){
    errors[0].className = 'hidden';
}
//reset messages
var messages = document.getElementsByClassName('message');
while (messages.length != 0){
    messages[0].className = 'hidden';
}
//reset highlights
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
while (fields.length != 0){
    fields[0].className = fields[0].className.replace('highlight', 'lowlight');
}

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` method is not supported by IE8. You can use [CSS-selectors](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) (e.g. `document.querySelector('.error')`) or us a [shim](https://gist.github.com/E01T/6088383) for `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: _.getElementsByClassName()_ originally returned a _live_ NodeList, so that would avoid the endless loop you mentioned since the body of the loop removes the class in question. Though shims for the method would not return a live list.  (I say "originally" because I believe the DOM4 specification changed it to return an HTMLCollection.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: you've got a point, didn't think of that. I'll remove that part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
document.querySelectorAll('.error')
```